# populate view based on multi-level model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, models

Suppose, I have models:

```
public class Person
{
  public sting Name {get;set;}
  public List<Book> Books {get;set;}
}

public class Book
{
  public sting NameBook {get;set;}
}
```

How represent view for Edit method based on Person model (MVC 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something along the lines of:

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Book)
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
}
```

and then you will define an editor template for the `Book` type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Book.cshtml`) which will be rendered for each element of the `Book` property collection (which by the way you would have named `Books` in order to follow standard conventions) on your view model:

```
@model Book
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NameBook)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.NameBook)
</div>
```

As far as your controller actions are concerned, it's pretty standard stuff:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var person = _personRepository.Get(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(person);
    } 
    _personRepository.Update(person);
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Comment: How can I add/remove row in View ?

Comment: @Shurokan, you may take a look at the following article if you want to achieve this using javascript: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/